# What's the difference between "ldr pc, _boot" and "b _boot"?

Tags: assembly, arm

I was examining a vector table for the ARM Cortex A9 and stumbled accross two types of instructions:

B _boot

and

LDR PC, _boot

Can someone explain to me the difference in using B or LDR? Both code should do the same but apparently there must be a difference. Has it something to do with the link register?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ldr reg, symbol` loads data from memory at that address, into the register.  Loading into PC is a memory-indirect jump.
It will only assemble and link if `_boot` is near enough for a PC-relative addressing mode to reach it, but that's likely if both are in the `.text` section.

`b symbol` sets PC = the *address* of the symbol.  It's direct relative jump.

The link register is no involved in either case because you use `b` not `bl` or `blx`.

---

#### `ldr pc, _boot`

Another way to do what `ldr pc, _boot` does:

```
   ldr  r0, =_boot         @ "global variable" address into register
   ldr  r0, [r0]           @ load 4 bytes from that symbol address
   br   r0                 @ and set PC = that load result
```

Assuming your `_boot:` label is in front of some code, rather than a `.word another_symbol`, **this is not what you want**.  You'd be loading some bytes of machine code and using it as an address.  (Setting PC to somewhere probably invalid.)

But if you do have `_boot: .word foobar` or something, then it is what you want.

---

#### `b _boot`

Or the equivalent of `b _boot` in terms of `ldr` would be to load the address from memory into PC.  That would mean you'd need a word in memory holding that address, instead of just the immediate relative displacement in the `b` encoding.

But ARM assemblers have a pseudo-instruction to do that:
`ldr pc, =_boot` will load that label address into PC, using a PC-relative addressing mode to load from a nearby literal pool.  Or instead of into PC directly, you could set up for a `br`.

```
  ldr  r0, =_boot       @ symbol address into register
  br   r0               @ jump to that symbol
```

This is not exactly equivalent: it's not position-independent because it's using absolute addresses, not just a relative branch.

Comment: Ok, so in short words, when using B the program jumps to an address specified by the lable _boot, but when using LDR the value of the memory region specified by the address in _boot is placed into PC, did I get it correctly?

And neither B _boot nor ldr pc, _boot change the value of the link register, right?

Comment: @Stone: yup, that's correct.

Comment: @old_timer: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "you can move that code around, before the VTOR". As far as I know you can use the VTOR to move the vector table location somewhere else. But how does that relate to using B or LDR pc for branching to an ISR?

Comment: Peters answer is about what is the difference and that is correct, I am trying to add the why do you see it one way sometimes and see it another.  Was trying not to compete with that answer.

Comment: maybe I will write a whole answer, will see.

Comment: I would not say it jumps to the address label _boot, while it does, it jumps some distanced from the current program counter.   the offset not the address is encoded in the instruction.  If properly encoded by the toolchain then that is the equivalent of the address _boot, yes.  If not relocated, if relocated then it jumps to the same handler, but at some other address.

Comment: @old_timer: Don't get me wrong, I very much appreciate that you try to explain me the background as this would be my next question anyway. I just don't understand what you mean... 
Are you saying that the B command does not branch correctly if the vector table is moved with VTOR but the ldr command would still get the branching correctly?

Answer (score 7):

Peter's answer covers the what.  This is an attempt at the why.  Why do you see some code uses b and some uses ldr pc.

Starting with an abbreviated exception table:

```
b reset
b handler_a
b handler_b
b handler_c

reset:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    b .
handler_a:
    b .
handler_b:
    b .
handler_c:
    b .
```

Which generates this:

```
10000000 <_stack+0xff80000>:
10000000:   ea000002    b   10000010 <reset>
10000004:   ea000003    b   10000018 <handler_a>
10000008:   ea000003    b   1000001c <handler_b>
1000000c:   ea000003    b   10000020 <handler_c>

10000010 <reset>:
10000010:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
10000014:   eafffffe    b   10000014 <reset+0x4>

10000018 <handler_a>:
10000018:   eafffffe    b   10000018 <handler_a>

1000001c <handler_b>:
1000001c:   eafffffe    b   1000001c <handler_b>

10000020 <handler_c>:
10000020:   eafffffe    b   10000020 <handler_c>
```

The address 0x10000010 is not encoded in the b(ranch) instruction.  Instead a pc relative offset is:

```
10000000:   ea000002 -2 b   10000010 <reset>
10000004:   ea000003 -1 b   10000018 <handler_a>
10000008:   ea000003 +0
1000000c:   ea000003 +1
10000010:   e3a0d902 +2 mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
```

The first instruction is encoded with a 2 as an immediate.  For this instruction this is in units of words.  The pc is two instructions ahead when executed, so pc+2 gets you to the reset handler 0x10000010.

For ldr pc:

```
ldr pc,reset_address
ldr pc,handler_a_address
ldr pc,handler_b_address
ldr pc,handler_c_address

reset_address    :  .word reset
handler_a_address:  .word handler_a
handler_b_address:  .word handler_b
handler_c_address:  .word handler_c

reset:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    b .
handler_a:
    b .
handler_b:
    b .
handler_c:
    b .
```

Which gives:

```
10000000 <_stack+0xff80000>:
10000000:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 10000010 <reset_address>
10000004:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 10000014 <handler_a_address>
10000008:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 10000018 <handler_b_address>
1000000c:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 1000001c <handler_c_address>

10000010 <reset_address>:
10000010:   10000020    .word   0x10000020

10000014 <handler_a_address>:
10000014:   10000028    .word   0x10000028

10000018 <handler_b_address>:
10000018:   1000002c    .word   0x1000002c

1000001c <handler_c_address>:
1000001c:   10000030    .word   0x10000030

10000020 <reset>:
10000020:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
10000024:   eafffffe    b   10000024 <reset+0x4>

10000028 <handler_a>:
10000028:   eafffffe    b   10000028 <handler_a>

1000002c <handler_b>:
1000002c:   eafffffe    b   1000002c <handler_b>

10000030 <handler_c>:
10000030:   eafffffe    b   10000030 <handler_c>
```

This instruction encodes using a byte offset:

```
10000000:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]
10000004:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]
10000008:   e59ff008 +0
1000000c:   e59ff008 +4
10000010:   10000020 +8 .word   0x10000020
```

The so one level of indirection the pc gets the value from the word in the address of pc+offset.  pc = [0x10000010]

Now note in both cases because we use labels and tools that do the work for us, computing the offsets for branch, the ldr pc, linking and placing the addresses for the handlers, etc.  Something we do not really want to do ourselves if we can avoid it.

Now take a very real situation where you boot the processor off of a flash.  And you are on a pre-VTOR ARM processor.   Some of these want to run an operating system.  So you may want one exception table for the bootloader (grossly over-complicated like u-boot for example, which is to some extent its own operating system).  Which means you want to have ram at 0x00000000.  ARM is not a chip vendor they make the processor core, chip vendors make the chip and make these decisions.  Some chip vendors will map a flash at let's say 0x10000000 as an example.  In order to boot and assuming the entry address is 0x00000000 (something the chip vendors control, but usually it is 0x00000000 for normal booting).  So when they release reset on the ARM core we need the contents 0x10000000 mapped to 0x00000000.   Memory is its own banks, flash, ram, peripherals, etc.  The chip vendor controls all of this and can make it fixed or can make it programmable, such that there is say signals and a control register that allow on reset fetches to 0x00000000 to go to the flash that is also mapped at 0x10000000 normally.   Maybe a small portion.  On boot/reset the fetch of 0x00000000 gets the instruction there be it a b or ldr pc (for normal exception table use, you have one instruction to get out of the table so that means b or ldr pc).

So for the reset both methods will work, assuming there is enough of the flash mirrored to 0x00000000 (for a successful design, it will be).

If you use the branch method for one of these chips then your pc when you branch to the reset handler (reset label) is 0x00000010 not 0x10000010, so you now need to get yourself to the right address.  Some folks would just orr 0x10000000 to the pc as a quick hack.  Or would ultimately use a ldr pc of some label.

Then you would be running from flash.  You would at some point want some ram and would map ram to address 0x00000000 (these chips exist, not an unheard of design).  And then start using it.  But you have the problem that you no longer have an exception table at the right address 0x00000000.  This is pre-VTOR, but even with VTOR you may want to think about all of this.  With the branch method you would want to think about maybe creating your own instructions that branch forward 0x10000000...If that is possible 0xea..xxxx.  I would have to look at the encoding but it is 0x10000000-8 / 4 or 0x10000000/4 - 2  or 0x04000000 - 2 and that will not fit clearly.  If we were trying to reach 0x8000 for example that would be 0x2000 - 2 which would fit in the instruction.   So we would want to do something like

```
0xe59ff008
0xe59ff008
0xe59ff008
0xe59ff008
0x10000000
0x10000004
0x10000008
0x1000000C
```

and write those ourselves starting at 0x00000000 so that if an exception comes in we do a load of an address and that address is the one in flash.

Now instead of we use the ldr method.  Then we boot, we are not entering reset with the address 0x00000020 but instead the desired 0x10000020, we do not have to mess with that address.  If we copy the first in this example 0x20 bytes from 0x10000000 to 0x00000000 then our handlers are all in place, we did not have to create any instructions or addresses, the tools did all the work we just copy the work.

Many/most processors use a vector table with addresses in the table, ARM in these processors use fixed addresses that you supply an instruction. And reset is the first one so if you were really building a binary with an entry point of 0x10000000 it certainly does not need to have a table, it only needs the entry point and code begins.

```
reset:
  mov sp,0x0x8000
  ...
```

Once booted you can build the handler in ram dynamically, generate the ldr pc instructions, fill in addresses into a table by having code that asks the linker for that address (write32(0x0004,(unsigned int)handler_a);).

Other hardware designs could have the flash at 0x00000000 and ram elsewhere.  And you may have the same desire to have a table with entries more than just reset and may wish to runtime change one of them.  The code would be linked for 0x00000000 and you cannot now change the vector table because it is in flash, so for that you would want to do something like this (if flash is at 0x10000000):

```
ldr pc,a
ldr pc,b
ldr pc,c
ldr pc,d

a:  .word 0x10000000
b:  .word 0x10000004
c:  .word 0x10000008
d:  .word 0x1000000C

reset_address    :  .word reset
handler_a_address:  .word handler_a
handler_b_address:  .word handler_b
handler_c_address:  .word handler_c

reset:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    b .
handler_a:
    b .
handler_b:
    b .
handler_c:
    b .
```

Creating:

```
00000000 <a-0x10>:
   0:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 10 <a>
   4:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 14 <b>
   8:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 18 <c>
   c:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 1c <d>

00000010 <a>:
  10:   10000000    .word   0x10000000

00000014 <b>:
  14:   10000004    .word   0x10000004

00000018 <c>:
  18:   10000008    .word   0x10000008

0000001c <d>:
  1c:   1000000c    .word   0x1000000c

00000020 <reset_address>:
  20:   00000030    .word   0x00000030

00000024 <handler_a_address>:
  24:   00000038    .word   0x00000038

00000028 <handler_b_address>:
  28:   0000003c    .word   0x0000003c

0000002c <handler_c_address>:
  2c:   00000040    .word   0x00000040

00000030 <reset>:
  30:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
  34:   eafffffe    b   34 <reset+0x4>

00000038 <handler_a>:
  38:   eafffffe    b   38 <handler_a>

0000003c <handler_b>:
  3c:   eafffffe    b   3c <handler_b>

00000040 <handler_c>:
  40:   eafffffe    b   40 <handler_c>
```

and on boot copy the four words at 0x0000 to 0x10000000, copy the four words at 0x20 to 0x10000010.  Then you can change the words at 0x10000010 if you want to change the handlers runtime.

With VTOR if you do not care to change the vectors while you are running and the flash is at 0x10000000, then you can use ldr pc for reset to get the pc pointed at flash not the mirror at 0x00000000.  And then on boot program VTOR to point at 0x10000000.  But if you want to dynamically change the address then the table needs to be in ram and you circle back to the days before VTOR.

So....

At an instruction level one loads the pc from a pc relative offset.  The other loads the pc from an address pointed to by a pc-relative offset.

At the system level, you are dealing with the exception table that most folks will put at the entry point in flash, and then deal with generating a table at address 0x00000000 if it is not already there.

And if you want to dynamically change the handlers for any reason, then your actual table (or the ones you modify at least) need to be in ram.

ldr pc is the most flexible, adds the most features for you but you ideally have to type a little bit more code.   If you have none of these problems, flash starts at 0x00000000 or you are not expecting any interrupts or exceptions so you do not need handlers, then ldr pc takes more bytes and more typing.  b(ranch) will work just fine.

The above is just one way to do each thing, you can use the tools other ways or do things manually so long as it functions...

Comment: Wow that was a lot to read, thanks for your detailed response.
I think I grasp the basic idea now, altough I had troubles understanding some of the examples. ### 
If b . branches to the current code (infinite loop), why is the offset of the pc 0xfffffe? Wouldn't this mean an offset of the current pc of 16777214? Why not use 0? ###
Your wrote "The pc is two instructions ahead when executed" is this because of pipelining? But isn't the number of pipeline stages architecture dependent? Why assume 2 then?

Comment: one could assume that at some point in the beginning arm had a pipeline such that the pc during execution was two ahead, address of instruction plus eight.   but certainly today, the cores are built to be compatible independent of their own internals

Comment: 0xF...FFE is a minus two yes?    if the pc is two ahead and you subtract two that is minus 2.   so to branch to the same instruction you need to subtract off the two instructions that the pc is ahead when executing

Comment: it is not an assumption it is just how it works.    thumb is the same which is 4 bytes. but when they added thumb2 that made it confusing and I want to say it is 4 bytes anyway instead of "two ahead" but I would have to play with some code to confirm that.

Comment: Of course, you are absolutely right! The offset encoding of b is signed!! That makes sens. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why ARM designed the architecture in a way that makes the PC point two words ahead? This makes it very confusing to think code through... they must have had a good reason I guess.

Comment: no doubt it was a pipeline thing.  maybe the guys are still alive and youc an ask them.

Comment: not necessarily uncommon, might see that on some ISAs just from fetching and not being pipelined, by the time they fetch all the bytes, then execute they are one or two or three bytes in and that is where the primitive pc is.   But now that you know/see how this ISA works, it is what it is, no big deal just do the math.

Comment: just like as you see to extend the range they dont use a byte offset in the branch, but a word offset, that gives. them four times the range

Comment: but the pc relative load, uses bytes, and that makes sense too.   Every instruction of every instruction set has rules, you just read and use the rules

Comment: But what happens if an unexpected branch happened or something else which leads to the pipeline being empty, where does the pc point in this situations? Can I rely on the fact that the pc ALWAYS points two bytes ahead in ARM architecture?

Comment: the pc is fake, these days there are multiple program counters.  Nobodey can compete with arm, your computer alone has more non-x86 processors than x86 processors, many of which are arm.   the instruction set works.   define "unexpected branch". how would that be possible?

Comment: the pipe cant be empty during the execution phase to get to execution that instruction has to get through fetch and decode, so even in the text-book type pipe, the pc is still pointing correctly.

Comment: you have at least one pc for fetching, one or more for branch prediction you have one for execution and a conditional one in case the execution follows the branch.

Comment: a program counter that contains the instruction being executed is the abnormal situation.  two ahead is as well, one ahead is no surprise.

Comment: same problem with mips and the branch shadow, that is all fake now too, and can be disabled so that your tools dont have to mess with it.

Comment: "define "unexpected branch"" - I was referring to a conditional branch, I thought that the prediction mechanism selects one way to go and the pipline is loaded with thoes instructions. If the prediction turns out to be wrong the pipe would have to be flushed and reloaded therefore the PC would not be ahead anymore in this brief section until the pipe is refilled with the correct branch - so did I think that this works. But I don`t have any deep insight in the matter

Comment: branch prediction which comes in a few flavors if available at all (and enabled). simply starts an additional fetch a few clocks early, only if that path gets taken does the pipe need to be flushed and the new instructions used.  You save the few clocks, maybe, from the extra fetch happening earlier than it would have.  And/or you created extra bus activity which slows down other activity, depends on what is going on in the system at that time.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for all the time and effort you put into replying to me and clarifying many things. My original question is now more than solved, I guess from this point on I can try to find out more on this matter by reading related articles. Thanks for your help!

Comment: how the two instructions function is documented by arm.  How individuals use them in the exception table is essentially personal preference, there is no right or wrong or best practice.

Comment: Meta discussion about this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413421/an-answer-disappeared-how-can-i-get-it-back-at-least-for-me-private